# Bootstrap tab not working in my registation form page

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

i have a code that consists of signin and signup details both in the same page but when i click the tabs its not switching to the respective tabs. I am new to bootstrap. please provide information to solve the issue

PS:- I don't want to add any of JQuery r JS code in this demo(i am trying with a pure html n bootstrap code)

here is the code of html

```css
body {
  padding-top: 90px;
}
.panel-login {
border-color: #ccc;

}
.panel-login>.panel-heading {
color: #00415d;
background-color: #fff;
border-color: #fff;
text-align:center;
}
.panel-login>.panel-heading a{
text-decoration: none;
color: #666;
font-weight: bold;
font-size: 15px;

}
.panel-login>.panel-heading a.active{
color: #029f5b;
font-size: 18px;
}
.panel-login>.panel-heading hr{
margin-top: 10px;
margin-bottom: 0px;
clear: both;
border: 0;
height: 1px;

}
.panel-login input[type="text"],.panel-login input[type="email"],.panel-login input[type="password"] {
height: 45px;
border: 1px solid #ddd;
font-size: 16px;
}
.panel-login input:hover,
.panel-login input:focus {
outline:none;
box-shadow: none;
border-color: #ccc;
}
.btn-login {
background-color: #59B2E0;
outline: none;
color: #fff;
font-size: 14px;
height: auto;
font-weight: normal;
padding: 14px 0;
text-transform: uppercase;
border-color: #59B2E6;
}
.btn-login:hover,
.btn-login:focus {
color: #fff;
background-color: #53A3CD;
border-color: #53A3CD;
}
.forgot-password {
text-decoration: underline;
color: #888;
}
.forgot-password:hover,
.forgot-password:focus {
text-decoration: underline;
color: #666;
}

.btn-register {
background-color: #1CB94E;
outline: none;
color: #fff;
font-size: 14px;
height: auto;
font-weight: normal;
padding: 14px 0;
text-transform: uppercase;
border-color: #1CB94A;
}
.btn-register:hover,
.btn-register:focus {
color: #fff;
background-color: #1CA347;
border-color: #1CA347;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css"/>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-b/U6ypiBEHpOf/4+1nzFpr53nxSS+GLCkfwBdFNTxtclqqenISfwAzpKaMNFNmj4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-h0AbiXch4ZDo7tp9hKZ4TsHbi047NrKGLO3SEJAg45jXxnGIfYzk4Si90RDIqNm1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
<div class="panel panel-login">
<div class="panel-heading">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-xs-6">
<a href="#" class="active">Login</a>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-6">
<a href="#">Register</a>
</div>
</div>
<hr>
</div>
<div class="panel-body">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-12">
<form id="login-form" action="#" method="post" role="form" style="display: block;">
<div class="form-group">
<input type="text" name="username" id="username" tabindex="1" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" value="">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<input type="password" name="password" id="password" tabindex="2" class="form-control" placeholder="Password">
</div>
<div class="form-group text-center">
<input type="checkbox" tabindex="3" class="" name="remember" id="remember">
<label for="remember"> Remember Me</label>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">
<input type="submit" name="login-submit" id="login-submit" tabindex="4" class="form-control btn btn-login" value="Log In">
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-12">
<div class="text-center">
<a href="#" tabindex="5" class="forgot-password">Forgot Password?</a>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</form>
<form id="register-form" action="#" method="post" role="form" style="display: none;">
<div class="form-group">
<input type="text" name="username" id="username" tabindex="1" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" value="">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<input type="email" name="email" id="email" tabindex="1" class="form-control" placeholder="Email Address" value="">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<input type="password" name="password" id="password" tabindex="2" class="form-control" placeholder="Password">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<input type="password" name="confirm-password" id="confirm-password" tabindex="2" class="form-control" placeholder="Confirm Password">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">
<input type="submit" name="register-submit" id="register-submit" tabindex="4" class="form-control btn btn-register" value="Register Now">
</div>
</div>
</div>
</form>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

i want to display both login and register display in the same page

here is the css code of the page

thanks in advance for providing the answers

Comment: Please do not copy/paste all your code here...

Comment: sorry i am new to stackoverflow this is my first question.. i will learn how to ask from now on thanks

Comment: You say you don't want to use jQuery/JS but it's the JS that makes the switching possible. This is why you include Bootstraps JS file at the top.

Comment: so there is no other way to do then?

Comment: @johnybravo Not with your code no. The code you wrote is generic grid code, it has no functionality for what you want. So you can either use simple JS or use Bootstraps Tabs. I'll add a demo.

Comment: Of course there is a way.. you can do it with pure `bootstrap` without adding any `js` or `jquery`, there is `Bootstrap Tabs and Pills` for doing this.

Comment: @pedram can you provide solution for the above code by doing that?

Comment: @pedram I mentioned Bootstraps Tabs...

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/8t2ogu9y/1/ check this out. I've almost figured it out in pure css. But for some reason it wont hide when i click the same target.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without JS, there isn't much you can do with your current code except convert it to use tabs. But here is a clean jQuery version. I've added comments to explain what the code does. Hopefully it's simple enough to understand.

```js
//On the login button click
$('#loginBtn').on('click', function(){
 
 //Fade out the register form
  $('#register-form').fadeOut(function(){
  
    //Fade in the login form
    $('#login-form').fadeIn();
    
  });
  
});

//On click of the register button
$('#regBtn').on('click', function(){

  //Fade out the login form
  $('#login-form').fadeOut(function(){
  
    //Fade in the register form
    $('#register-form').fadeIn();
    
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  padding-top: 90px;
}

.panel-login {
  border-color: #ccc;
}

.panel-login>.panel-heading {
  color: #00415d;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
}

.panel-login>.panel-heading a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #666;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 15px;
}

.panel-login>.panel-heading a.active {
  color: #029f5b;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.panel-login>.panel-heading hr {
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  clear: both;
  border: 0;
  height: 1px;
}

.panel-login input[type="text"],
.panel-login input[type="email"],
.panel-login input[type="password"] {
  height: 45px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.panel-login input:hover,
.panel-login input:focus {
  outline: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  border-color: #ccc;
}

.btn-login {
  background-color: #59B2E0;
  outline: none;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 14px;
  height: auto;
  font-weight: normal;
  padding: 14px 0;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border-color: #59B2E6;
}

.btn-login:hover,
.btn-login:focus {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #53A3CD;
  border-color: #53A3CD;
}

.forgot-password {
  text-decoration: underline;
  color: #888;
}

.forgot-password:hover,
.forgot-password:focus {
  text-decoration: underline;
  color: #666;
}

.btn-register {
  background-color: #1CB94E;
  outline: none;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 14px;
  height: auto;
  font-weight: normal;
  padding: 14px 0;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border-color: #1CB94A;
}

.btn-register:hover,
.btn-register:focus {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #1CA347;
  border-color: #1CA347;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-b/U6ypiBEHpOf/4+1nzFpr53nxSS+GLCkfwBdFNTxtclqqenISfwAzpKaMNFNmj4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-h0AbiXch4ZDo7tp9hKZ4TsHbi047NrKGLO3SEJAg45jXxnGIfYzk4Si90RDIqNm1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
      <div class="panel panel-login">
        <div class="panel-heading">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-6">
              <a id="loginBtn" href="#" class="active">Login</a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-6">
              <a id="regBtn" href="#">Register</a>
            </div>
          </div>
          <hr>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
              <form id="login-form" action="#" method="post" role="form" style="display: block;">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <input type="text" name="username" id="username" tabindex="1" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" value="">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <input type="password" name="password" id="password" tabindex="2" class="form-control" placeholder="Password">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group text-center">
                  <input type="checkbox" tabindex="3" class="" name="remember" id="remember">
                  <label for="remember"> Remember Me</label>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">
                      <input type="submit" name="login-submit" id="login-submit" tabindex="4" class="form-control btn btn-login" value="Log In">
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                      <div class="text-center">
                        <a href="#" tabindex="5" class="forgot-password">Forgot Password?</a>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </form>
              <form id="register-form" action="#" method="post" role="form" style="display: none;">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <input type="text" name="username" id="username" tabindex="1" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" value="">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <input type="email" name="email" id="email" tabindex="1" class="form-control" placeholder="Email Address" value="">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <input type="password" name="password" id="password" tabindex="2" class="form-control" placeholder="Password">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <input type="password" name="confirm-password" id="confirm-password" tabindex="2" class="form-control" placeholder="Confirm Password">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">
                      <input type="submit" name="register-submit" id="register-submit" tabindex="4" class="form-control btn btn-register" value="Register Now">
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </form>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**UPDATE:** Here is a pure Tabs solution.

```css
body {
  padding-top: 90px;
}

.panel-login {
  border-color: #ccc;
}

.panel-login>.panel-heading {
  color: #00415d;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
}

.panel-login>.panel-heading a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #666;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 15px;
}

.panel-login>.panel-heading a.active {
  color: #029f5b;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.panel-login>.panel-heading hr {
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  clear: both;
  border: 0;
  height: 1px;
}

.panel-login input[type="text"],
.panel-login input[type="email"],
.panel-login input[type="password"] {
  height: 45px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.panel-login input:hover,
.panel-login input:focus {
  outline: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  border-color: #ccc;
}

.btn-login {
  background-color: #59B2E0;
  outline: none;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 14px;
  height: auto;
  font-weight: normal;
  padding: 14px 0;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border-color: #59B2E6;
}

.btn-login:hover,
.btn-login:focus {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #53A3CD;
  border-color: #53A3CD;
}

.forgot-password {
  text-decoration: underline;
  color: #888;
}

.forgot-password:hover,
.forgot-password:focus {
  text-decoration: underline;
  color: #666;
}

.btn-register {
  background-color: #1CB94E;
  outline: none;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 14px;
  height: auto;
  font-weight: normal;
  padding: 14px 0;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border-color: #1CB94A;
}

.btn-register:hover,
.btn-register:focus {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #1CA347;
  border-color: #1CA347;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-b/U6ypiBEHpOf/4+1nzFpr53nxSS+GLCkfwBdFNTxtclqqenISfwAzpKaMNFNmj4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-h0AbiXch4ZDo7tp9hKZ4TsHbi047NrKGLO3SEJAg45jXxnGIfYzk4Si90RDIqNm1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
      <div class="panel panel-login">
        <div class="panel-heading">
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab" role="tablist">
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link active" id="login-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#login-form" role="tab" aria-controls="login" aria-selected="true">login</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" id="register-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#register-form" role="tab" aria-controls="register" aria-selected="false">register</a>
  </li>
</ul>
          <hr>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
            <div class="tab-content" id="myTabContent">
              <form id="login-form" class="tab-pane  show active" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="login-tab" action="#" method="post" role="form" >
                <div class="form-group">
                  <input type="text" name="username" id="username" tabindex="1" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" value="">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <input type="password" name="password" id="password" tabindex="2" class="form-control" placeholder="Password">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group text-center">
                  <input type="checkbox" tabindex="3" class="" name="remember" id="remember">
                  <label for="remember"> Remember Me</label>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">
                      <input type="submit" name="login-submit" id="login-submit" tabindex="4" class="form-control btn btn-login" value="Log In">
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                      <div class="text-center">
                        <a href="#" tabindex="5" class="forgot-password">Forgot Password?</a>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </form>
              <form id="register-form" class=" fade tab-pane " action="#" method="post" role="form" >
                <div class="form-group">
                  <input type="text" name="username" id="username" tabindex="1" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" value="">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <input type="email" name="email" id="email" tabindex="1" class="form-control" placeholder="Email Address" value="">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <input type="password" name="password" id="password" tabindex="2" class="form-control" placeholder="Password">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <input type="password" name="confirm-password" id="confirm-password" tabindex="2" class="form-control" placeholder="Confirm Password">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">
                      <input type="submit" name="register-submit" id="register-submit" tabindex="4" class="form-control btn btn-register" value="Register Now">
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </form>
              </div> <!-- /tab-content -->
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: i cannot use any of jquery or javascript code for my project.. its completely must be in bootstrap. if there is any other way around please do help.. thanks for this answer

Comment: @johnybravo Like I said, you can use tabs. But tabs **IS** using Javascript.. you do realise that, right?

Comment: `Tabs` using `bootstrap.js` not additional code, OP already included this library. OP said need `pure BS` well, if you want `BS` you should include `BS.js` anyway, @ProEvilz make a snippet with tabs and that solve OP's problem.

Answer (score 0):

[check it out](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_pills_dynamic&stacked=h) In bootstrap there is Bootstrap tab. By using that you can achieve your goal

Answer (score 0):

Pure CSS solution: the best I can achieve. Maybe someone else can fix the start-state.

check Jsfiddle since the snippet isnt working properly: https://jsfiddle.net/8t2ogu9y/4/

HTML:

```css
body {
  padding-top: 90px;
}
.panel-login {
border-color: #ccc;

}
.panel-login>.panel-heading {
color: #00415d;
background-color: #fff;
border-color: #fff;
text-align:center;
}
.panel-login>.panel-heading a{
text-decoration: none;
color: #666;
font-weight: bold;
font-size: 15px;

}
.panel-login>.panel-heading a.active{
color: #029f5b;
font-size: 18px;
}
.panel-login>.panel-heading hr{
margin-top: 10px;
margin-bottom: 0px;
clear: both;
border: 0;
height: 1px;

}
.panel-login input[type="text"],.panel-login input[type="email"],.panel-login input[type="password"] {
height: 45px;
border: 1px solid #ddd;
font-size: 16px;
}
.panel-login input:hover,
.panel-login input:focus {
outline:none;
box-shadow: none;
border-color: #ccc;
}
.btn-login {
background-color: #59B2E0;
outline: none;
color: #fff;
font-size: 14px;
height: auto;
font-weight: normal;
padding: 14px 0;
text-transform: uppercase;
border-color: #59B2E6;
}
.btn-login:hover,
.btn-login:focus {
color: #fff;
background-color: #53A3CD;
border-color: #53A3CD;
}
.forgot-password {
text-decoration: underline;
color: #888;
}
.forgot-password:hover,
.forgot-password:focus {
text-decoration: underline;
color: #666;
}

.btn-register {
background-color: #1CB94E;
outline: none;
color: #fff;
font-size: 14px;
height: auto;
font-weight: normal;
padding: 14px 0;
text-transform: uppercase;
border-color: #1CB94A;
}

.expand{display:none;}
.expand:target{display:block;}

#register-form + .expand{display:none;}
.btn-register:hover,
.btn-register:focus {
color: #fff;
background-color: #1CA347;
border-color: #1CA347;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css"/>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-b/U6ypiBEHpOf/4+1nzFpr53nxSS+GLCkfwBdFNTxtclqqenISfwAzpKaMNFNmj4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-h0AbiXch4ZDo7tp9hKZ4TsHbi047NrKGLO3SEJAg45jXxnGIfYzk4Si90RDIqNm1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
<div class="panel panel-login">
<div class="panel-heading">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-xs-6">
<a href="#login-form" class="active">Login</a>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-6">
<a href="#register-form" class="">Register</a>
</div>
</div>
<hr>
</div>
<div class="panel-body">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-12">
<form id="login-form" class="expand" action="#" method="post" role="form">
<div class="form-group">
<input type="text" name="username" id="username" tabindex="1" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" value="">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<input type="password" name="password" id="password" tabindex="2" class="form-control" placeholder="Password">
</div>
<div class="form-group text-center">
<input type="checkbox" tabindex="3" class="" name="remember" id="remember">
<label for="remember"> Remember Me</label>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">
<input type="submit" name="login-submit" id="login-submit" tabindex="4" class="form-control btn btn-login" value="Log In">
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-12">
<div class="text-center">
<a href="#" tabindex="5" class="forgot-password">Forgot Password?</a>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</form>
<form id="register-form" class="expand" action="#" method="post" role="form">
<div class="form-group">
<input type="text" name="username" id="username" tabindex="1" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" value="">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<input type="email" name="email" id="email" tabindex="1" class="form-control" placeholder="Email Address" value="">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<input type="password" name="password" id="password" tabindex="2" class="form-control" placeholder="Password">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<input type="password" name="confirm-password" id="confirm-password" tabindex="2" class="form-control" placeholder="Confirm Password">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">
<input type="submit" name="register-submit" id="register-submit" tabindex="4" class="form-control btn btn-register" value="Register Now">
</div>
</div>
</div>
</form>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```